# how can i integrate a feedback form in my android app that should open when i click on log out button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

XML Code:

Following is the code for the `XML` file of the feedback form.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
tools:context="com.example.administrator.feedbackform.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout">

        </include>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView_Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your Feedback Is Important For Us!"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="10pt">
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText_Enter_your_name"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter your name here"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColorHint="#00E676"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText_Enter_your_Email"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Please enter your email here"
            android:textColorHint="#00E676"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText_FeedbackBody"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint1"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColorHint="#00E676"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:background="#FFFDE7"
            >
        </EditText>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/CheckBoxResponse"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Are you sure you want to submit? Check the box then!"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            >
        </CheckBox>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonSendFeedback"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="sendFeedback"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
        </Button> 
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Java Code:

Following is the code for the java file of the feedback form.

```
package com.example.administrator.feedbackform;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    Button Submit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_Enter_your_name);
        String name = nameField.getText().toString();

        final EditText emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_Enter_your_Email);
        String email = emailField.getText().toString();

        final EditText feedbackField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_FeedbackBody);
        String feedback = feedbackField.getText().toString();

        final CheckBox responseCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxResponse);
        boolean bRequiresResponse = responseCheckbox.isChecked();

        Submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonSendFeedback);
        Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Thanks! Your Feedback is submitted.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Assume that there is a Logout button, so, please suggest how can i display a feedback form before the user can exit the app. I'll be grateful if you can answer the exact code for this !

Comment: where is your `exit` button ?

Comment: @W4R10CK Suppose there is an exit button in some screen then what should be the code on that button to call the above mentioned form?

Comment: If there is a button and a user clicks on it, you must provide a `Dialog` asking for feedback, not stating a activity for that, Use custom dialog for that.

Comment: If the user is attempting to close the app (because they want to do something else?) why would the user take the time to fill out a survey?  And if they do fill it out, it might be negative because of the placement of the survey.  Perhaps a better user experience would be to pop up the survey during a natural pause between major activities?

Comment: @AndrewS hey! can you suggest some link or piece of code for making this pop-up?

Answer (score 2):

@GuneetKaur,

1) What you can do is when you press the logout button you can call another Activity that contains your feedback screen.

2) You can show the Alert Dialog when you click the logout button.

3) If you want the same when user clicks the back button to exit the app, then you can override the onBackPress() method and remove the super.onBackPress() from it, then you can maintain the flag that if the user click on back then you can check if feedback is given then you can change the flag to true and then call the finish() method or the super.onBackPress()

4) Same in the case for Alert Dialog.

### Please do tell me what code do you need I shall provide the same.

Adding some code for reference

```
logout_button.setOnClickListener(
 new OnClickListener(View view){
  // Call your Dialog for feedback
          OR
  // Call your Feedback Activity 
 }
);

//Generally this below method is called in Activity from where the Application gets closed



 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
      //Remove this super.onBackPressed();

      // Call your Dialog for feedback
          OR
      // Call your Feedback Activity 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is show a dialog.Define a new alert dialog.set its view with the layout you have for the feedback form.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, null,false);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

EditText editText =(EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.label_field);
```

like this you can instantiate all your layout items(like a submit button        which the user will hit after filling all the posts).
  Then at the click of your logout button you can show thw alertdialog with following code.

AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();

alertDialog.show();

Answer (score 1):

To specifically accomplish what you ask, you should set an `onClickListener` programmatically in your code. In that code (which I assume you place in the original activity), you would create an intent to start the feedback form, and then call the `finish` method in the following line. Calling `finish` will remove the original activity from the back stack, so that when they press back or `finish` the feedback form, the app should close.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use alert dialogbox when you click logout

```
                 ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog();
                 public class ViewDialog {
                    alert.showDialog(MainActivity.this, "GIVE FEADBACK");

       public void showDialog(Activity activity, String msg){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.updatedialog);

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog);
        text.setText(msg);

        Button dialogUpdate = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.update);
        Button dialogcancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        Button dialogremindme = (Button)     dialog.findViewById(R.id.remindeme);
        TextView textView= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.machhint1);
        TextView textView2= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.machhint2);




        dialogcancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialogUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //do code for for update fedabck
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialogremindme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        //if you dont want to send feadback
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }
}
PLEASE  MAKE XML YOURSELF
```